# how to get specific data from Firebase (by criterions)

Tags: firebase, android-studio

I building an application like Tinder and I am storing the users locations on Firebase.
I want to write a function for receiving only users that live 6 kilometers or less from my location (need a ready list when he start looking).
how can I do that?